# Why does canceling of a local notification triggers a repeating local notification (that produced that local notification)?

Tags: ios, notifications

I have an iOS app with a (daily) repeating local notification that when `some` conditions are meet fires a new local notification. A local notification that must be shown within the app (with a banner) and within the `notifications view`. I have implemented it roughly within the AppDelegate as a proof of concept and that works(tm).

From a block in the banner I remove the `onetime` local notification from the `notifications view` with `cancelLocalNotification`. But surprisingly the repeating localnotification is re-triggered when firing `UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelLocalNotification(<the one time notification>)` - why ? And how do I prevent this ?

```
...
import JCNotificationBannerPresenter

...
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Setup local notifications support
        let notificationType: UIUserNotificationType
        = [UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Badge, UIUserNotificationType.Sound]
        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationType,
                                                  categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)

        // Clean up and reset
        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
        application.cancelAllLocalNotifications()

        NSLog("Setup one repeating notification")
        let n = UILocalNotification()
        n.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 15)
        n.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
        n.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
        n.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
        n.userInfo = ["id": "dailyreminder"]
        n.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.Day

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(n)

        return true
    }

    ...

    func application(application: UIApplication,
                     didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {

        NSLog("application(... didReceiveLocalNotification/////////////////////////")
        NSLog(notification.description)

        let state = application.applicationState
        if let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
           let id = userInfo["id"] as? String
           where id != "dailyreminder" {
            switch state {
            case UIApplicationState.Active:
                NSLog(String(format: "%@ > UIApplicationState.Active", id))
                JCNotificationCenter.enqueueNotificationWithTitle(
                    notification.alertTitle,
                    message: notification.alertBody,
                    tapHandler: { () -> Void in
                        NSLog("Banner click ///////////////////////////////////////////////")
                        // 1. Go to somewhere in the app 
                        // 2. Cancel the notification from the `notifications view`
                        UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelLocalNotification(notification)
                        // `cancel` results in an additional call up of the "dailyreminder" ~ why?
                    })
            case UIApplicationState.Inactive:
                NSLog(String(format: "%@ > UIApplicationState.Inactive", id))
                // This is called up when user selects the notification within the `notifications view`
                // and canceled by user touch.
            default:
                let desc = state.rawValue.description
                NSLog(String(format: "%@ > Unexpected app state: %@", id, desc))
            }
        }

        if let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
           let id = userInfo["id"] as? String
           where id == "dailyreminder" {
            NSLog("Repeating daily reminder was called ~ lets fire a noti to show the user")

            // Some condition checks that need to be true before firing the local notification
            if true {
                let n = UILocalNotification()
                n.fireDate = nil
                n.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
                n.applicationIconBadgeNumber = ++UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber
                n.userInfo = [
                    "id": "onetimenotification"
                ]
                n.alertTitle = "One time notification title"
                n.alertBody = "One time notification body"

                UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(n)
            }
        }

    }

    ...
```

### Update 1

I have put up the full example on [github](https://github.com/pellekrogholt/spike-ios-notification-repeating-cancel/tree/90460e230089c6bece5bd493de67454e210c685a).

### Update 2

Ok I gave it another shoot. Having the cancel notification outside a block works (but don't fit the scenario):

```
case UIApplicationState.Active:
    NSLog(String(format: "%@ > UIApplicationState.Active", id))
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelLocalNotification(notification)
```

I also like to eliminate that the `JCNotificationBannerPresenter` was causing the odd behavior so I tried with the new ios altertController:

```
case UIApplicationState.Active:
    NSLog(String(format: "%@ > UIApplicationState.Active", id))
    let alertController = UIAlertController(
            title: "Daily reminder title",
            message: "Daily reminder description.",
            preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { _ in
    NSLog("Do nothing ////////////////////// ")
    }
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
    let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { (action) in
        NSLog("OK was pressed ////////////// ")
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelLocalNotification(notification)
    }
    alertController.addAction(OKAction)

    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    let v = self.window!.rootViewController!
    v.presentViewController(alertController,
                            animated: true,
                            completion: {})
```

This did unfortunately reproduce the odd behavior so it tastes like its something with the combination of block and `UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelLocalNotification(notification)`...

Answer (score 0):

You have not cancel the repeating notification i.e. your daily reminder notification in your `didReceiveLocalNotification` method.  You have cancel the notification `where id != "dailyreminder"` whereas you repeating notification have `id == "dailyreminder"`. Check your conditions in  `didReceiveLocalNotification`

Comment: Pardon my question / description was unclear I don't want to remove the repeating notification but only the `onetime` notification when the banner within the app is clicked. Because the `onetime` notification is already fired I cant look it up by userInfo["id"] within `UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduledLocalNotifications`.

Comment: I seriously don't understand why you are scheduling another notification on receiving of a notification. What i have understand is that you need to perform some task when your repeating notification is triggered. right? if that's the case then in your  didReceiveLocalNotification  check the user info of that notification & if it has id == "daily reminder" perform your task , show custom view or anything you want. No need of scheduling another notification and then performing your desired task.

Comment: Fair enough. The repeating daily reminder notification must always fire. The onetime notification might not be fired under some conditions. In the example these conditions are just always set to true. If the `onetime` notification is fired I would within the app like to be able to remove the `onetime` notification from the global/system notifications view. Pardon me if I'm explaining it in an awkward way. I still believe in the use case :)

Comment: ok if your onetime notification  won't fired under some condition then you can AND that condition with your id condition in your  didReceiveLocalNotification method.